# How to convert a shell output into python dictionary

Tags: python, shell

I need to convert a shell output which is a string to python in order to perform manipulation in that. For reference, my code is shown below.

```
p = Popen('sudo df -h /var/lib/docker/volumes/myvolume2/_data', shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
output = p.stdout.read()
print (output)
```

Current Output:
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6       109G   32G   72G  31% /

````
Expected Output
```{
'Filesystem' :/dev/sda6,
'Size': 109G,
'Used': 32G,
'Use%': 31%
}```
````

Comment: Do you need `sudo`? If not, try `shutil.disk_usage()`

Comment: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/docker/volumes/myvolume2/_data'

Comment: Got above error

Comment: How to overcome sudo requirment

Comment: I don't know, that's why I asked if you needed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a simple ad-hoc parser just with the basic tools:

```
p = Popn(...)
output = p.stdout.read().decode()      # from bytes to str
header, data, *_ = output.split('\n')  # split to lines
header = header.replace('Mounted on', 'Mounted_on')  # fix a two word field
df = dict(zip(header.split(), data.split()))         # split to fields and combine

print (df)
```

Comment: Thanks @VPfB. I need one more help for avoiding sudo in this command. If I execute the command without sudo then it will show  permission error

Comment: @EdwardArrow If your account does not have the required permission, then you need the sudo. That's probably all help you can get on this topic. I see no problem in `sudo df -h filesystem`, it is much more secure than `sudo python script.py` If you want to further improve your progam, avoid `shell=True` and list all the Popen arguments explicitly.